# ListView padding before and after items

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

My `ListView`s all add a huge amount of padding before and after their children.

For example I have the following `ListView` in my master

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=App"
             x:Class="Pages.Master"
             Title="Menu">
  <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModel:MasterViewModel />
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>

  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}"
            ItemSelected="ListView_OnItemSelected"
            BackgroundColor="Red">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          <Label Text="S" BackgroundColor="White" />
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

And it renders the following:

[image]

And as soon as you scroll just a little it'll reveal the first element (i.e. the top red space is equal to the height)

[image]

Similarly you can keep scrolling until the last item completely disappears (i.e. the bottom red space is equal to the height)

I don't change the properties/styling of ANY of the views in code - it's all done in the XAML, so why is there such a huge amount of space before and after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a problem with the rendering of ListView.Header and ListView.Footer

I added the following to my list view XAML and it removed the giant padding:

```
<ListView.Header>
  <StackLayout HeightRequest="0" />
</ListView.Header>
<!-- ItemTemplate -->
<ListView.Footer>
  <StackLayout HeightRequest="0" />
</ListView.Footer>
```

As this problem was affecting all of my list views, I chose to instead add it as a globally applied style in my App.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="ListView">
  <Setter Property="Header">
    <Setter.Value>
      <StackLayout HeightRequest="0" />
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Footer">
    <Setter.Value>
      <StackLayout HeightRequest="0" />
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```